# Content not changing when clicking an item from a slider (javascript and php)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, slider

I have created a slider for a sub nav mobile version. If you click on an item from this slider, the content below should change. I just had to code the javascript for the slider and the backend developer had to connect it with the content.

**Desktop is working but mobile is not working** (content is not changing) and the backend developer is not working on this project anymore. I can see on the desktop code, that is different from the mobile one (see screenshot attached). The mobile version is missing the href I think. But don't know what should I do since I don't know php.

**JS code for slider**:

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName("phonenav__blue__slide").length) {
    var slideIndex = 1;
    phonenavshowSlides(slideIndex);

    phonenavshowSlides(slideIndex);

    function phonenavplusSlides(n) {
        phonenavshowSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
        phonenavshowSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function phonenavshowSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("phonenav__blue__slide");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        if (n > slides.length) {
            slideIndex = 1
        }
        if (n < 1) {
            slideIndex = slides.length
        }
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        // for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        //     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        // }
        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        // dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    }
}
```

**php code:**

```
<?php

use function MIA\Theme\acf_constructor_get_element as get_element;
use function MIA\Theme\constructor_section_attr as section_attr;
use function MIA\Theme\constructor_section_class as section_class;

$data   = get_element();
$tabs   = $data['tabs'];
$titles = wp_list_pluck( $tabs, 'tab-title' );
//nav__blue__wrapper__container__item--private
?>
<div class="<?php echo section_class( "private-tab-accordion", $data ); ?>" <?php section_attr( $data ) ?>>
    <section class="nav__blue nav__blue--private" id="navblue">
        <?php if ( count( $titles ) > 1 ) { ?>
            <div class="nav__blue__wrapper" id="navblue__wrapper">
                <div class="nav__blue__wrapper__container">
                    <?php foreach ( $titles as $key => $title ) { ?>
                        <?php if ( $key ) { ?>
                            <span class="nav__blue__wrapper__container__line"></span>
                            <div class="nav__blue__wrapper__container__item tab">
                                <a href="#tab-<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $title ?></a>
                            </div>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <div class="nav__blue__wrapper__container__item tab nav__blue__wrapper__container__item--private">
                                <a href="#tab-<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $title ?></a>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </section>
    <section class="phonenav__blue" id="navbluePrivatePhone">
        <?php foreach ( $titles as $key => $title ) { ?>
            <div class="phonenav__blue__slide tab">
                <a><?php echo $title ?></a>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <a class="phonenavprev" onclick="phonenavplusSlides(-1)"><img
                    src="<?php echo THEMROOT ?>/static/assets/arrow-prev.svg"></a>
        <a class="phonenavnext" onclick="phonenavplusSlides(1)" id="phonenavnext"><img
                    src="<?php echo THEMROOT ?>/static/assets/arrow.svg"></a>

    </section>
    <div class="accordion-tabs">
        <?php foreach ( $tabs as $key => $item ) { ?>
            <?php $active = $key == 0 ? "active" : ''; ?>
            <div class="tab-item <?php echo $active; ?>" id="tab-<?php echo $key ?>">
                <section class="two__columns">
                    <div class="two__columns__wrapper">
                        <div class="two__columns__wrapper__column"><?php echo wpautop( $item['text_column_1'] ) ?></div>
                        <div class="two__columns__wrapper__column">
                            <?php echo wpautop( $item['text_column_2'] ) ?>
                            <?php if ( ! empty( $item['links'] ) ) { ?>
                                <?php foreach ( $item['links'] as $link ) { ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $link['link']['url']; ?>"
                                       target="<?php echo $link['link']['target']; ?>"
                                       style="text-decoration: none;"
                                       class="accordion__link accordion__link--top">
                                        <?php echo acf_image( $link['icon'], 'accordion__link__img accordion__link__img--top' ) ?>
                                        <p class="accordion__link__text"><?php echo $link['link']['title']; ?></p>
                                    </a>
                                <?php } ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section class="accordion__wrapper">

                    <p class="accordion__wrapper__intro"><?php echo $item['title']; ?></p>
                    <?php if ( ! empty( $item['accordions'] ) ) { ?>
                        <?php foreach ( $item['accordions'] as $tKey => $accordion ) { ?>
                            <button class="accordion__wrapper__item"><?php echo $accordion['title']; ?></button>
                            <div class="accordion__wrapper__panel">
                                <?php if ( ! empty( $accordion['text'] ) ) { ?>
                                    <?php echo wpautop( $accordion['text'] ); ?>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php if ( ! empty( $accordion['links'] ) ) { ?>
                                    <?php foreach ( $accordion['links'] as $link ) { ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $link['link']['url']; ?>"
                                           target="<?php echo $link['link']['target']; ?>"
                                           style="text-decoration: none;"
                                           class="accordion__link">
                                            <?php echo acf_image( $link['icon'] ) ?>
                                            <p class="accordion__link__text"><?php echo $link['link']['title']; ?></p>
                                        </a>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="accordion-line"></div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                </section>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you so much in advance!!!

[image: slider screeenshot]

[php code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTYhq.png)

Comment: Hey @kiner_shah thanks a lot for your quick answer but the code is also in the post

Comment: Where is the JS code located? Is it within a `script` tag or is it a separate file? If it is a separate file, is it linked to the HTML/PHP page using those functions?

Comment: Also, did you try to debug by opening the inspector and placing breakpoints at different lines?

Comment: @kiner_shah JS code is in a separate file and is linked to the html page

Comment: So you want to change the div, when you click on the div itself (not the left and right arrow buttons)? If so, you just need to attach an event listener to those divs.

Comment: @kiner_shah it's not related to the arrows. The arrows are working well. 
When I click "Grundpfandrechte" I want the text bellow to change. We have on the backend (wordpress) different text content for each element we have on the blue nav, the slider. Sorry I don't know if this is clear enough.

Comment: @kiner_shah but phonenavplusSlides is called when you click on the arrows, to display a different word/item/link inside the blue nav and that's working well. Every time I click on the arrows, content inside the blue nav is changed. Did I misunderstood you?

Comment: @kiner_shah I appreciate so much your help but I said it was not related to the arrows. The text I want to change is the text bellow the blue nav (Bei einem Immobilienkauf....). That content is uploaded to the wordpress backend and this is working on the desktop version. That's why I thought it was a problem related to the php file. Code for desktop is different to the code for mobile. And that's why I uploaded a screenshot pointing to the desktop and to the mobile code.

Comment: ***When I click "Grundpfandrechte" I want the text bellow to change*** I got it.

Comment: Which part of HTML code is associated with this text "Bei einem Immobilienkauf..."?

Comment: this text is associated to this two sections:
<section class="two__columns">
<section class="accordion__wrapper">

And this two sections, the backend developer grouped them together inside <div class="accordion-tabs">

thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you tell which is the exact HTML tag under which that data is populated? Those sections are too big with many tags so difficult to understand.

Comment: it is this tag:
<p class="accordion__link__text">

Comment: I think you should check the source code generated by PHP by Right Click > View Page Source. If the link isn't working, probably the `href` isn't being properly populated from PHP. For example, I mean this line: `<a href="<?php echo $link['link']['url']; ?>"...`

Comment: yes @kiner_shah I did that and I'm pretty sure that's the problem. But the backend developer is not participating in the project anymore and I don't know php so I don't know how to code this properly

Comment: Really don't know Wordpress so not sure from where is data obtained, but it seems all the required data is inside `$tabs` PHP variable. Maybe you can try to backtrace the source of its data.